# Call a class method with a multi level Module structure in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some modules to be included in my controller classes. These modules define `before_filter`:

```
module BasicFeatures
  def filter_method
    ...
  end
  def self.included(base)
    base.before_filter(:filter_method)
    ...
  end
end

module AdvancedFeatures
  include BasicFeatures
  ...
end
```

And the classes:

```
class BasicController < ApplicationController
    include BasicFeatures
end

class AdvancedController < ApplicationController
    include AdvancedFeatures
end
```

1. When `BasicFeatures` module is included in `AdvancedFeatures` module, there are no `before_filter` methods in it.
2. The `AdvancedController` didn't get the `before_filter` call.

I need both my controllers to get the `before_filter` without any code duplication. I don't know if I am using the best approach so, I'm open to any suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is why `ActiveSupport::Concern` was created.

```
module BasicFeatures
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_filter :require_user
  end

  def this_is_an_instance_method
    'foo'
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def this_is_a_class_method
      'bar'
    end
  end
end

class SomeClass
  include BasicFeatures
end

SomeClass.new.this_is_an_instance_method #=> 'foo'
```

You can also nest them — that is, create concerns that include concerns — and everything will work as expected. And [here are the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).

Comment: Very nice @coreyward. I didn't know that `AS::Concern` handled nesting.

Comment: omg @coreyward, it works like a charm! Rails always surprising me!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Instead of including the module in AdvancedFeatures, You can include the BasicFeatures module on the class including AdvancedFeatures

```
module BasicFeatures
    def filter_method
      #code....
    end

    #some others basic methods...

    def self.included(base)
      base.before_filter(:filter_method)
      #some other class method calls
    end
end

module AdvancedFeatures
  def self.included klass
    klass.class_eval do
      include BasicFeatures
    end
  end

  #some advanced methods
end
```